# How do I promote a function that returns a String with singletons?

Tags: haskell, singleton-type

Using stack with lts-9.2 (and singletons-2.1), I have this:

```
   $(singletons [d|
       data EventScans
        = PassThrough
        | SuiteProgress

       -- cn :: EventScans -> [Char]
       cn PassThrough = "all-events"
       cn SuiteProgress = "suite-progress"
    |])
```

I can't give this function a type signature and the inferred type signature is`cn :: IsString t => EventScans -> t`. AFAIK `IsString` doesn't singletonize.

Without the type signature on `cn` I get the `Cn` type family as expected. If I try to add the type signature I get:

```
* Expected kind `[Char]', but `"all-events"' has kind `Symbol'
* In the type `"all-events"'
  In the type family declaration for `Cn' (haskell-stack-ghc)
```

What's the right way to do this?

**edit** If I try to include the type signature `cn :: IsString t => EventScans  -> t` I get the following error:

```
Variable `a_agPb' used as both a kind and a type
 Did you intend to use TypeInType? (haskell-stack-ghc)
Not in scope: type constructor or class `SIsString'
  Perhaps you meant `IsString' (imported from Data.String) (haskell-stack-ghc)
```

Comment: Your way is fine - `IsString` is handled just fine by `singletons` (at least for me - this code works fine). Note that the inferred type is `.. -> String` unless you have `OverloadedStrings` enabled, so if you really want the simple return type, put this code in a module without it. Or, just have `cn' :: EventScans -> String; cn' = cn` somewhere.

Comment: @user2407038 I edited to make the question a bit clearer.

Comment: The error seems to be telling you to set -XTypeInType. Does that help?

Comment: @HTNW unfortunately not :-(

Comment: The code you posted originally, without a type signature on `cn`, works fine (i.e. leave the type to be inferred).

Comment: I could leave the type inferred in this case (although I prefer not to). But I'm interested in the underlying problem, and whether there's a way round it.

Answer (score 0):

From the related issue I opened on github, this is coming about because `IsString` doesn't singletonize yet. See https://github.com/goldfirere/singletons/issues/267 for details.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to disable OverloadedStrings, or you need to be explicit about their type, by doing:

```hs
$(singletons [d|
       data EventScans
        = PassThrough
        | SuiteProgress

       -- cn :: EventScans -> [Char]
       cn PassThrough = ("all-events" :: String)
       cn SuiteProgress = ("suite-progress" :: String)
    |])
```

I think it doens't want to do this because now you're asking for 2 layers of polymorpism (value, and type level). I doubt you need it so just be explicit.

But the thing you're making here doesnt' really need singletons anyway.
Singletons is only neccisary for going from value to type, in this case you know all values and therefore can go back to plain ol' typefamilies:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies        #-}

module Main where

import           Data.Proxy
import           GHC.TypeLits

test1 :: String
test1 = getStat $ Proxy @PassTrough

test2 :: String
test2 = getStat $ Proxy @SuiteProgress

data PassTrough
data SuiteProgress

type family Cn d :: Symbol where
  Cn PassTrough = "all-events"
  Cn SuiteProgress = "suite-progress"

getStat :: forall a b . ((Cn a) ~ b, KnownSymbol b) => Proxy a -> String
getStat _ = symbolVal $ Proxy @b
```